# while load pdf in webview i am getting Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1032a04f0) to 'NSURL' (0x1032a21b0). error

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am trying to load pdf in `webView` but api link is come from api and I want to open that link in `webView` which is actually on another `viewController` so I am passing link to that view and load into `webView` but I am getting error like this:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1032a04f0) to 'NSURL' (0x1032a21b0).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let view: PDFViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFViewController") as! PDFViewController

    let pdf = eCataLogList[indexPath.row]["pdf_file"]
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: (pdf as? URL)!)
   // let request = NSURLRequest(url: pdf as! URL);
    view.pdf_web.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: 1. Do not use `NSURLRequest` in Swift, use `URLRequest`. 2. `pdf` isn't a `URL`, it's a `String`.

Comment: ohk sur i will try it Thanks if any query then i will again cmnt it

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your pdf string to url. Use following code,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let view: PDFViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFViewController") as! PDFViewController
    let pdf = eCataLogList[indexPath.row]["pdf_file"]
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: pdf))
    view.pdf_web.loadRequest(request)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good point you check the error in debugger (debutants don't do it often).

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1032a04f0) to 'NSURL'
>   (0x1032a21b0).

Let's translate it:

At some point in your code, you are trying to cast an `NSString` object (That's the part `__NSCFString`) into a `NSURL`. That means, that you are trying to tell the compiler that this String can be a NSURL, and it's telling you NO at runtime.

Here is the line: `(pdf as? URL)!`

Ask you this:
Can a `String` object be translated as such as an `URL` object? Can a `UIImage` be translated as such a `CBPeripheral`? 
No, not really.?
Classes/structs have meaning, different goal and different uses.

Quick fix:

```
let pdfURLString = eCataLogList[indexPath.row]["pdf_file"] //So that's a String
let pdfURL = URL.init(string: pdfURLString)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: pdfURL!)
```

Now let's review more your code:

Avoid using NSStuff when there is a "Swift" version: `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` => `URLRequest`, etc. Of course, you can use the bridges and cast with a as a `URLRequest` into a `NSURLRequest` and reverse, but see that in your current code you are doing `NSURLRequest` to `URLRequest`, while you could have use URLRequest from the start. That's just adding noises to do each time `as`.

Avoid force unwrapping when possible, that's the use of `!`. If it fails (it's nil), it will crash. Instead use `guard let` or `if let`

```
guard let view: PDFViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFViewController") as? PDFViewController else {
    print ("Error in initializing the PDFViewController")
    return
}

let pdfURLString = eCataLogList[indexPath.row]["pdf_file"]
if let pdfURL = URL.init(string: pdf) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: pdfURL)
    view.pdf_web.loadRequest(request)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
} else {
    print("Ooops, \(pdfURLString ?? "pdfURLString for row \(indexPath.row)") doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
}
```

*Note:* 
I explicitly wrote `URL.init(string: someURLString)`, but you can write `URL(string: someURLString)`.